# Any framework or tool is available to achieve swagger definition as the auto generation process for AWS Chalice?

Tags: python, swagger, chalice

I'm using AWS chalice for API development and deployed. Currently, I'm about to implement swagger definition for my API's and I don't want to do the swagger definition creation process as the manual. Is there any framework or tool available especially for the chalice to auto-generate the swagger definition using docstring or any other techniques? Actually I tried with the apispec-chalice framework, But it's not working as expected. Any information related to chalice with swagger creation will be great and helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Its good to use native [ApiSpec](https://apispec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)(https://apispec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

1. First, Add following to your app.py

```
from apispec import APISpec

#Create an APISpec
spec = APISpec(
    title='AppName',
    version='1.0.0',
    openapi_version="3.0.2",
    plugins=[],
)
```

2. Then run, `chalice generate-models` from terminal in your project repo.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 have nothing to do with each other: generating a model using `chalice generate-models` does not use the `apispec` library in any way, and vice versa.

Comment: @han-tyumi - What you trying to insinuate? Are you suggesting, just using `chalice generate-models` would generate swagger definitions as well? Please guide.

Comment: Yes, `chalice generate-models` is "enough" in the sense that it does produce a valid swagger definition file. However it doesn't allow any customization as of today. The `apispec` step that you mention is not necessary for this, and it actually doesn't work, because there's not updated plugin for making `chalice` work with `apispec`.

Answer (score 2):

you could give this apispec plugin a try if anyone's still having this problem: https://github.com/TestBoxLab/chalice-spec